# Why this cronjob wont run

Tags: linux, debian, cron, cronjob

On debian squeeze as user root I add this cronjob with "crontab -e"

```
*/1 * * * *     root /usr/sbin/ntpdate ptbtime1.ptb.de >> /var/log/ntpdate.log
```

But this cronjob will not run, there is also nothing into /var/log/ntpdate.log after insert this cronjob I restart the service with /etc/init.d/cron restart but nothing happend.

What can I do to let this cronjob start.

Comment: What's in your `cron` log?

Comment: `*/1` is the same as `*`, semantically ("Run every minute"). Have you tried the latter?

Comment: There is no /var/log/cron.log and in my syslog there is no entry with cron

Comment: By the way, **please** don't do this. It doesn't actually synchronize your clock's *rate*, which is probably what you really want. It also contributes to the "thunderclap effect" (massive burst of traffic to and from public NTP servers at the second boundary) which harms everyone's NTP accuracy by increasing latency and jitter. If you must do this, make sure you have obtained *permission* to do this for each NTP server you plan to query in this way.

Comment: It is only a workaround for round about a week.

Comment: There are VPS providers that specifically request this, because their VMs can't track NTP servers properly.  Having said that, they generally use their own local NTP servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you used `crontab -e` instead of dropping a file in `/etc/cron.d`, your line has too many fields.  You only specify the user in the latter case.

Removing the username from your crontab, it should look like this:

```
*/1 * * * *    /usr/sbin/ntpdate ptbtime1.ptb.de >> /var/log/ntpdate.log
```

Syntax errors would have been written into `/var/log/cron.log`; it's always worth checking that file if you have problem with cron.